# QGIS SCP doesn't stack all bands for Sentinel 2

Tags: qgis, raster, classification, sentinel-2, scp

I've been following various tutorials to try and stack and then eventually classify images from Sentinel 2, but after downloading the images and running the band set tool, it simply only stacks 4 bands and it doesn't seem to stack the 4 from the the first 4 in the list either. I haven't downloaded the images using SCP as it doesn't seem to find images I can find directly from Copernicus. I've tried running the band set tool several times, ordering them, specifying the wavelengths to use by pointing to Sentinel 2 and indicating that it needs to create a band set raster (not a virtual one).

Has anyone come across this? I'm a bit stumped as I can't see any references to this happening to anyone else.